# The alarmManager do not wake up my code when the app is destroyed why?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I created a reminder system, it works properly, when I just close the application it works. But when I destroy the application by closing all the recent applications, the alarmmanager does not wake up the application here is my code:

the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".TimeAlarm" />
```

The method:

```
public void addAlarm(int id, int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(year, month, day, hour, minute);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimeAlarm.class);
        PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), operation);
    }
```

The class receiver:

```
public class TimeAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int notificationID = 3;
        NotificationManager notificationManager;
        Notification myNotification;

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);

        myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle("Exercise of Notification!")
                .setContentText("Do Something...")
                .setTicker("Notification!")
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ics_close)
                .build();

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(notificationID, myNotification);
    }
}
```

thanks!

Comment: If your application is destroyed how is it supposed to receive the broadcast?

Comment: This is the problem, I want to create reminder, if I do not have the application in background I do not receive the reminder, and the user will miss the reminders, how to make sure that the application is never destroyed? I know it's possible because there are apps that do it